# Replace character while user is typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Trying to replace a space with the character _

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
        username = textField.text!
        username = username.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil)
        textField.text! = username
    }
    return true
}
```

Trouble is, the space is replaced after the character following the space is typed.

Comment: did you try that in the func textfielddidchange?

Comment: @Douglas solved it - I thought textfielddidchange was a delegate method but seems not

Comment: Why don't you use the passed parameters `range` and `replacementString`? You are throwing way the benefit of this method. And why don't you check if the typed character is a space character. In almost all cases `replacingOccurrencesOf` is called for nothing.

Comment: DanielT answer is correct. With this method you are using, username still does not have the space in it, that is what you are evaluating. That's why your space only gets changed on the next character. Return true or false will accept or dump the actual character.  Damyan answer is also correct if you want to keep the same method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `textField(_, shouldChangeCharactersIn:, replacementString:)` is a query, you should not be putting side effects there. Instead make an IBAction and attach it to the `editingChanged` UIControlEvent...

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    sender.text = sender.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make logic in key down , key up event ...
To ask in key down event is key_code=='ENTER'(i think its 13 code) , and if it is write in input _ and return false , to break the event and do the job right... I had made similar things with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and you will get the main idea

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var text = textField.text! + string

    if (text.range(of: " ") != nil) {
        text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil)
        textField.text! = text
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the user is trying to replace the middle of the string with a string in a paste operation because it assumes that the `replacementString` is being appended which isn't necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this extension for String

```
extension String {
    func removingWhitespaces() -> String {
        return components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()
    }
}
```

Using:

```
if textField.tag == 0 {
    username = textField.text!
    username = username.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil)
    username.removingWhitespaces()
    textField.text! = username
}
return true
```